# Can you use VPS for login and bypass VPN detection?

Tags: vpn, vps

Can I bypass VPN detection with VPS? Instead of using VPN, I use VPS for another IP location and while doing that I can bypass VPN detection, right?

Like, they don't know where I am and they use the location of the VPS instead, right?

Comment: You have 2 different problems and questions smashed together here. Can a site know you are using a VPS and block you just like they can do with VPN detection? Yes. Can you remotely connect to another machine to make it seem like you are browsing from that remote machine? Of course.

Answer (score 0):

The *VPN detection* does not detect the usage of VPN per se, as a technology, but that the connection is coming from an IP address that is a known exit point for a VPN product.

Therefore, you could create your own VPN through a VPS, making your connections originating from that remote machine. It might work unless the *VPN detection* starts blocking that subnet for the reason it belongs to a VPS provider instead of an ISP providing consumer lines.

Comment: Since people use AWS to host their own VPNs, a lot of blocking filters block cloud service IPs